# Primefaces FileUpload: handle firewall error blocking upload

Tags: jsf, primefaces

We have a JSF application that is currently working and live that uses Primefaces 7.0. The application allows users to upload files using the Primefaces FileUpload component which we then handle and process.

The firewall team is forcing a firewall to sit in front of the upload process which will block upload requests from hitting the application if it deems the file to not be suitable and return a 503 error to the browser. I am struggling to work out how we can handle the 503 error within the JSF application as the request never hits the server and I can't find a suitable attribute we can add to the FileUpload component that would listen for the 503 (tried using **onerror** as shown in code below but unfortunately it doesn't get called when the 503 error occurs). Without handling this error, nothing is presented to the user to suggest anything happened. Ideally we would present a growl message to the user asking them to try a different file type.

Below is the code currently for the FileUpload component however I'm not sure if it's any use as I'm looking more for advice than a code fix.

Anyone have any idea on how to potentially handle the 503?

Thanks

```
            <p:fileUpload widgetVar="upload" id="upload"
                disabled="#{user.filesRemaining eq 0}" label="SELECT FILES"
                fileUploadListener="#{controller.handleFileUpload}"
                styleclass="smallCommandButton" mode="advanced"
                dragDropSupport="true" auto="true"
                allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(jpeg|jpe|jpg|png|pdf)$/i" sizeLimit="10485760"
                invalidSizeMessage="Image files must be under 10MB in size"
                invalidFileMessage="Only JPG, PNG or PDF files can be uploaded"
                onerror="#{controller.handleUploadError()}"
                onstart="PF('uiBlocker').show()"
                oncomplete="PF('uiBlocker').hide()">
            </p:fileUpload>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do anything if the firewall in front of you is rejecting the request with a 503.  Its never getting to your server so there is nothing for you to handle right?

Comment: Agreed, that's as far as my train of thought went. I was hoping there was a solution I wasn't able to think of

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, I needed to add the below code to my fileUpload component, 'arguments' carries the information for the error:

```
onerror="handleUploadError(arguments)"
```

and then create the corresponding javascript function to handle the error e.g.

```
    function handleUploadError(arguments) {
        if(arguments[0].status === 503) {
            **create message for user here**
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Awesome job! Thanks for posting back.